# trouble initializing openGL with visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012

For my includes, I have the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

However, when I try to compile, I get a whole slew of errors, not related to any of the source code I am using.

Error   1   error C2825: '_Iter': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 364 1   mp4

Error   2   error C2039: 'iterator_category' : is not a member of '`global namespace''  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 364 1   mp4

Error   3   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'iterator_category'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 364 1   mp4

Error   4   error C2602: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category' is not a member of a base class of 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 364 1   mp4

Error   5   error C2868: 'std::iterator_traits<_Iter>::iterator_category' : illegal syntax for using-declaration; expected qualified-name   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 364 1   mp4

...etc...

I am not sure what xutility file is, or why the compiler is complaining about it. I highly suspect it has something to do with the way I have openGL set up with VS 2012, but I am not sure. Can anyone spot a problem with my includes?

Comment: did you include your paths in the build options of your solution?

Comment: what is this and how do I do it?

Comment: I did manually put the glut.h into the GL folder, the other two files were already there

Comment: [FreeGLUT](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) or ancient [Nate GLUT](http://user.xmission.com/~nate/glut.html)?

Comment: can't use it, it's for a class

Comment: Try including the GL includes before your system includes. This sometimes matters for OpenGL on Windows...

Comment: still not working :/ can someone tell me what @Need4Sleep meant?

Comment: Do not include both "math.h" and "cmath". They contain mostly the same declarations, but one in the global namespace while the other in the `std::` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

instead of -

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
```

just use -

```
#include <GL/GL.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use my mental powers to look into your other code. ;-P

You have something like that:

```
#include "myheader.h"
#include <iostream>
```

And in the file `myheader.h` you have a class declaration -or maybe a struct- but you missed the ending semicolon -or maybe the braces are mismatched.

Or maybe you have unmatched `#ifdef` / `#endif` clauses.

Then the compiler is all confused when it reads the standard C++ headers and spews all these unreadable errors.

As a rule of thumb, the include headers should be in order from most standard to less standard:

1. Language files.
2. System files.
3. Library files.
4. Local project files.

Remember that included files are simply concatenated textually, and then the result is compiled all together. So an error at the end of one header file may trigger a compiler error in the next one.